# Undetected browser extremely inconsistent with ungoogled chromium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

My original goal was to access a **Cloudflare** protected website, and refresh the driver on that page, but that didn't work.

Now I am trying simply to go to the website, and then to open windows, as so:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

This works fine when I use **geckodriver** for **selenium python**, but in this case the code will go over the first instruction without doing anything, and die on the second one giving an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I have tested with **Vivaldi**, which didn't work, and with **Brave**, which is blocked by apparmor by default on my machine. Is this an issue with undetected *chromedriver* in general, or will using actual Google Chrome fare any better?